# SQL LEFT JOIN syntax

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one called "oficinas" and the other called "registrovisitas".

oficinas has columns: idofi, ofi, address
registrovisitas has columns: idregistro, ofi, user, fechavista

I want to select all values where address is like "de" with all the info in table "oficinas" and the associated max(fechavisita) as date group by ofi.

```
SELECT a.ofi of, a.address dir

FROM oficinas a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ofi, max(fechavisita) ffg FROM registrovisitas ) b ON (a.ofi=b.ofi)

WHERE a.ofi LIKE %de%
```

But the max date (fechavisita) doesn't appear, what am I doing wrong?

In the table registrovisitas there are more than one register on the same ofi on different dates by different users, I think is not necessery put group by in the select dont?

Comment: Sidenode: `Left/Right` Joins are implicit `Outer` joins, so the keyword can be ommited.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the column `ffg` to the outer select clause

```
SELECT a.ofi of, a.address dir, ffg 
FROM oficinas a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
   SELECT ofi, max(fechavisita) ffg 
   FROM registrovisitas
   GROUP BY ofi
) b ON a.ofi = b.ofi
WHERE a.ofi LIKE %de%
```

You also need to group by `ofi` in the inner query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.idofi, a.ofi, a.address dir, 
       (select max(fechavisita) from registrovisitas where ofi=A.idofi group by ofi)

FROM oficinas a 

WHERE a.ofi LIKE %de%
```